# How to show hierarchy row like parent child using SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using blog comments in my application where I insert every comment row in one table so if any of them reply on a particular comment that on clicked `commentid` I am inserting as `replyid` in new row.

Below is the Screen shot:

[image: Table picture]

Here you can see for `commentid` 24 and 26 is having `replycommentid` 23.
I need a query to show 24 and 26 just after 23. Because 23 is the parent of 24 and 26.

Here is the setup script for table layout and sample data:

```sql
USE [myDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails]    Script Date: 11/12/2016 6:36:04 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails](
    [CommentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CommentUserName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [CommentText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CommentApprovedByUserID] [int] NULL,
    [CommentPostDocumentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CommentDate] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [HtmlComment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CommentIsSpam] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_Blog_MainComment_CommentIsSpam]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CommentIsApproved] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_Blog_MainComment_CommentIsApproved]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CommentEmail] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CommentInfo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ReplyCommentID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID]) VALUES (22, N'Vikash', N'This is main comment', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2016-11-12 17:36:25.637' AS DateTime), N'<div class="main-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pCommentorName"><span id="sCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Vikash</span><span id="sBlogPostedDate">Nov12,2016 5:35PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogCommentDetails">This is main comment</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li><img src="assets/svg/components/blog-detail/icon_reply.svg" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnComment" href="#" target="_self">::blogdetailsReply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'vikash.kr@sonata-software.com', NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID]) VALUES (23, N'Megha k', N'This is reply comment', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2016-11-12 17:39:04.250' AS DateTime), N'<div class="reply-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pBlogReplyCommentorName"><span id="sReplyCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Megha k</span><span id="sBlogReplyCommentDate">Nov12,2016 5:38PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogReplyCommentDetails">This is reply comment</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li><img class="contributors-list" src="assets/svg/components/blog-detail/icon_reply.svg" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnCommentReply" href="#" target="_self">::blogdetailsReply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'megha.k@sonata-software.com', NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID]) VALUES (24, N'Siddappa H', N'This is reply text.', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2016-11-12 17:39:58.847' AS DateTime), N'<div class="main-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pCommentorName"><span id="sCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Siddappa H</span><span id="sBlogPostedDate">Nov12,2016 5:39PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogCommentDetails">This is reply text.</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li><img src="assets/svg/components/blog-detail/icon_reply.svg" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnComment" href="#" target="_self">::blogdetailsReply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'siddappa.h@sonata-software.com', NULL, 23)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID]) VALUES (25, N'Suresh P', N'This is reply comment', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2016-11-12 17:40:44.470' AS DateTime), N'<div class="reply-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pBlogReplyCommentorName"><span id="sReplyCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Suresh P</span><span id="sBlogReplyCommentDate">Nov12,2016 5:40PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogReplyCommentDetails">This is reply comment</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li><img class="contributors-list" src="assets/svg/components/blog-detail/icon_reply.svg" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnCommentReply" href="#" target="_self">::blogdetailsReply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'suresh.p@sonata-software.com', NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID]) VALUES (26, N'Vikash', N'This is reply text', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2016-11-12 17:41:44.673' AS DateTime), N'<div class="reply-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pBlogReplyCommentorName"><span id="sReplyCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Vikash</span><span id="sBlogReplyCommentDate">Nov12,2016 5:40PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogReplyCommentDetails">This is reply text</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li><img class="contributors-list" src="assets/svg/components/blog-detail/icon_reply.svg" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnCommentReply" href="#" target="_self">::blogdetailsReply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'vikash.kr@sonata-software.com', NULL, 23)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] OFF
GO
```

All suggestions are welcome!

I added three insert query also in below:

Valex, please insert this query in the table which is "INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID], [IsRejected]) VALUES (58, N'Vicky', N'Test', 0, 1, CAST(N'2016-12-02 11:51:07.270' AS DateTime), N'VickyDec2,2016 11:47AM

Test

  Reply

', 0, 1, N'vicky@gmail.com', NULL, NULL,0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID]) VALUES (61, N'Billu', N'This is comment test', 0, 1, CAST(N'2016-12-02 12:35:40.220' AS DateTime), N'BilluDec2,2016 12:34PMThis is comment test

  Reply

', 0, 1, N'billu@gmail.com', NULL, 58)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID]) VALUES (62, N'Rakesh', N'This is rakesh test', 0, 1, CAST(N'2016-12-02 12:37:42.133' AS DateTime), N'RakeshDec2,2016 12:36PMThis is rakesh test

  Reply

', 0, 1, N'rakesh@gmail.com', NULL, 58)

I am editing my question now.
Please check the screen shot below:
[image: TableStructure]

I used the query which is below:

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT CommentID ,

                     CommentPostDocumentID ,
                     CommentIsApproved,
                     CommentDate ,
                     ReplyCommentID ,
                     CommentUserName,
                     CommentID AS ThreadID ,
                     CAST( CommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr
              FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
              WHERE ReplyCommentID IS NULL
              UNION ALL
              SELECT T.CommentID ,

                     t.CommentPostDocumentID ,
                     t.CommentIsApproved,
                     T.CommentDate ,
                     T.ReplyCommentID ,
                     T.CommentUserName,
                     CTE.ThreadID ,
                     PathStr + '-'+ CAST( T.ReplyCommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr
              FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
              JOIN CTE 
              ON T.ReplyCommentID = CTE.CommentID
              WHERE T.ReplyCommentID IS NOT NULL )
            SELECT *
            FROM CTE
            WHERE CommentPostDocumentID = 18 AND CommentIsApproved=1
            ORDER BY ThreadID ,
                        PathStr ,
                        CommentDate DESC
```

Below is the image for showing comment:
[image]

Below is the expected structure:

1. Vikash comment
2. Sid is replied on vikash comment.
3. Megha is commented on vikash so megha comment is up than Sid under parent Vikash.
4. QE replied on Megha comment so he should be up than Sid but it is in last row.

Comment: k i am editing and adding scripts also for this table.

Comment: Can any one will reply on my question i am still waiting for my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use recursive CTE. Here is the adaptation [from your later question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40928903/1554034)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT CommentID, CommentUserName, CommentText,CommentDate,ReplyCommentID,
          CommentID as ThreadID,
          CAST(CommentID as varchar(MAX)) as PathStr
   FROM Blog_CommentDetails as T 
   WHERE ReplyCommentID IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT T.CommentID, T.CommentUserName, t.CommentText,T.CommentDate,
          T.ReplyCommentID,
          CTE.ThreadID,
          PathStr+'-'
          +CAST(T.ReplyCommentID as varchar(MAX)) as PathStr
   FROM Blog_CommentDetails as T 
   JOIN CTE ON T.ReplyCommentID = CTE.CommentID
   WHERE T.ReplyCommentID IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY ThreadID,PathStr,CommentID, CommentDate desc
```

Result:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ CommentID ║ CommentUserName ║      CommentText      ║       CommentDate       ║ ReplyCommentID ║ ThreadID ║ PathStr ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║        22 ║ Vikash          ║ This is main comment  ║ 2016-11-12 17:36:25.637 ║ NULL           ║       22 ║ 22      ║
║        23 ║ Megha k         ║ This is reply comment ║ 2016-11-12 17:39:04.250 ║ NULL           ║       23 ║ 23      ║
║        24 ║ Siddappa H      ║ This is reply text.   ║ 2016-11-12 17:39:58.847 ║ 23             ║       23 ║ 23-23   ║
║        26 ║ Vikash          ║ This is reply text    ║ 2016-11-12 17:41:44.673 ║ 23             ║       23 ║ 23-23   ║
║        25 ║ Suresh P        ║ This is reply comment ║ 2016-11-12 17:40:44.470 ║ NULL           ║       25 ║ 25      ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Valex, i added three new insert query in this question above please insert it. after insert you will find three username vicky, billu, and suresh so here vicky is the parent of billu and suresh. and according to the comment date suresh is the last commented person so rakesh should be upper than billu but still here billu is showing first and rakesh is second using your query.

Comment: @Vikash  I've added these 3 inserts (Changing  vicky's ReplyCommentID to NULL not 0 as in your insert). On the equal level sorting goes according the last `ORDER BY ThreadID,PathStr,CommentID`. So If billu, and suresh are on the same level they ordered using `CommentID` if you want to order them according `CommentDate` then chenge `CommentID` to `CommentDate` in this last ORDER BY.

Comment: No Valex, Rakesh and billu are not at the same level first billu is commented on vicky reply then in last rakesh has commented so according to the expected system rakesh comment will be up and billu will be down under vicky. Are you getting my point? If you have any doubt please ask to me.

Comment: @vikash I mean they both under the same vicky's post so they have the same calculated path and you can order them as you wish as explained in my prior comment.

Comment: That is the solution i needed how to make them in order on who is commented last should be up?

Comment: Valex, I tried this query only it's need to add commentdate order by desc so whoever is doing last comment that is seat up under of the parent. your rest of the code are fine.

Comment: Valex, I edited my question again failed in some of the scenario. Please look up into this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want either the full hierarchy or even a portion of it, with the proper sequence

> **EDIT - Removed Concat() for 2008**

```
Declare @Top  int = 23 --null             --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 23
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by CommentID) as varchar(500))
            ,CommentID
            ,ReplyCommentID
            ,Lvl=1
      From   [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails]
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ReplyCommentID,-1) else CommentID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(p.Seq+'.'+cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.CommentID) as varchar(25)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.CommentID
            ,r.ReplyCommentID
            ,p.Lvl+1
      From   [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] r 
      Join   cteP p on r.ReplyCommentID = p.CommentID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.CommentID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.CommentID )
Select A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.CommentID
      ,A.ReplyCommentID
      ,A.Lvl
      ,CommentText = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + C.CommentText
      -- Include any other fields from [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] alias C
 From cteR1 A 
 Join cteR2 B on A.CommentID=B.CommentID
 Join [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] C on A.CommentID=C.CommentID
 Order By A.R1
```

Returns

[image]

If @Top was set to 23 (for example), the return would be

[image]

I should add, cteR2 is not necessary, but it does indicate scope and/or Parent or Leaf level.

Answer (score 2):

You could order it like the smippet shown below:

```
select coalesce(replycommentid, commentid) as sequence, ...
order by sequence, ...
```

A parent row will use it's own id as the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, you want each comment followed by its replies before any (non-reply) following comment.  I think what you want is simply this:

```
select * from Blog_CommentDetails
order by coalesce(ReplyCommentID, commentID), CommentID
```