# Insert a row between two rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, logic

I have a table like this, which shows which user commented on which parent thread.

```
ParentID  CommentID UserName  CommentDateTime
58         58       Vicky     2016-12-02 11:51:07.270
58         61       Billu     2016-12-02 12:35:40.220
58         62       Rakesh    2016-12-02 12:37:42.133
```

If suppose a comment is made to the 2nd row, a new commentid is generated which is 63

I want to write a sql query which list the rows in the below order :

```
ParentID  CommentID UserName  CommentDateTime
58         58       Vicky     2016-12-02 11:51:07.270
58         61       Billu     2016-12-02 12:35:40.220
61         63       Rakesh    2016-12-02 13:37:42.133
58         62       Rakesh    2016-12-02 12:37:42.133
```

Could you please help me in writing a logic/SQL for this?

Comment: How many replies can a given parent comment have?  Is there a variable number of replies?

Comment: SQL data is inherently **unordered** - so you **cannot** insert a row between two existing rows - only add it to the end of the table. You only ever get an **order** when you select the data from the table, and explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` clause ...

Comment: You can delete existing and re-enter again by arranging using temp table.

Comment: @Suraz it still needs to be implicitly ordered when you retrieve the data. SQL Server does not guarantee the order otherwise

Comment: Sql Server insert the rows **physically in the order of primary key** and retrieve the rows in the order of primary key (if not `order by` is specified)

Answer (score 1):

If I've got it right you want to output records in the desired order not insert them into the table. Here we see a TREE of posts so I think you should use a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx). For each node we build a PATH string and then sort nodes using this path string:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ParentID, CommentID, UserName, CommentDateTime,
          ParentID as ThreadID,
          CAST(ParentID as varchar(MAX)) as PathStr
   FROM T 
   WHERE CommentID = T.ParentID 

   UNION ALL

   SELECT T.ParentID, T.CommentID, T.UserName, T.CommentDateTime,
          CTE.ThreadID,
          PathStr+'-'
          +CAST(T.CommentID as varchar(MAX)) as PathStr
   FROM T 
   JOIN CTE ON CTE.CommentID = T.ParentID
   WHERE T.CommentID <> T.ParentID 
)

SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY ThreadID,PathStr
```

I've added more nodes to example table so here is the result:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ ParentID ║ CommentID ║ UserName ║     CommentDateTime     ║ ThreadID ║   PathStr   ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║       58 ║        58 ║ Vicky    ║ 2016-12-02 11:51:07.270 ║       58 ║ 58          ║
║       58 ║        61 ║ Billu    ║ 2016-12-02 12:35:40.220 ║       58 ║ 58-61       ║
║       61 ║        63 ║ Rakesh   ║ 2016-12-02 13:37:42.133 ║       58 ║ 58-61-63    ║
║       58 ║        62 ║ Rakesh   ║ 2016-12-02 12:37:42.133 ║       58 ║ 58-62       ║
║      158 ║       158 ║ Vicky    ║ 2016-12-02 11:51:07.270 ║      158 ║ 158         ║
║      158 ║       161 ║ Billu    ║ 2016-12-02 12:35:40.220 ║      158 ║ 158-161     ║
║      161 ║       163 ║ Rakesh   ║ 2016-12-02 13:37:42.133 ║      158 ║ 158-161-163 ║
║      161 ║       164 ║ Rakesh   ║ 2016-12-02 13:37:42.133 ║      158 ║ 158-161-164 ║
║      158 ║       162 ║ Rakesh   ║ 2016-12-02 12:37:42.133 ║      158 ║ 158-162     ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Valex, yes i just need the query like CTE where i can show the value like shown above. I integrated your code but result is blank. If you use this link "http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14271418" where i asked first question to show the child under parent and got the answer. Now the issue is if a new user comments under of the parent his comment will be up under of the parent. You can get the table structure also in the given link.

Comment: @Vikash: I guess it's blank due to the structure of the posts tree is not the same. In this (current) question a start post has got a link to itself (58,58). In the earlier question a start post has got `replycommentIId = NULL` instead. So just correct may answer and change two conditions `WHERE CommentID = T.ParentID` => `WHERE CommentID IS NULL` and the second condition `WHERE T.CommentID <> T.ParentID ` => `WHERE T.CommentID IS NOT NULL`. That will help.

Comment: @Vikash: I've added [adaptation of my answer as an answer to your earlier question please use it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40933557/1554034)

Comment: I have edited my question from my previous question as the link is in above comment. Please go through that and give me solution.